# How to replicate a polygon over several points with different locations in Arcgis?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, polygon, paste

[image: 1= Is the polygon that I want to replicate. 2= the points represents the location where the replicated polygons should be.]1 will stay [1]]I have two shapefiles, one is a polygon and the other is points.
I would like to create a new shapefile which has the shape of the polygon in all the places that there is points. I would like to replicate the polygon under the points.

1= the polygon that I want to replicate. 2= the points represents the location where the replicated polygons should be (one polygon per point).

Comment: Hi, just to be clear, are you trying to select polygons that contain points and save the selected polygons in a new file?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format. Then, I suggest you [edit] your question to include a few screenshots illustrating what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You appear to have two discrete logins. Please use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge the accounts.

Comment: Hi Ana, I assume this is ArcGIS, and that in some places points lie on/within polygons. If so, "Select by Location" on the polygons using the points. Then Export the polygons to a new layer; by default, only the selected ones will be exported. The concept is the same in other GIS, like QGIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arcpy and the [da.Search/Update/InsertCursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/data-access-using-cursors.htm):

```py
import arcpy

points = 'placehere' #Change
polygon = 'copyme' #Change. Must only contain one polygon which is used as template. This feature class will modified so backup/make a copy if you want to keep one unchanged.

coordinates = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(points,'SHAPE@XY')] #List point coordinates
fieldnames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(polygon) if not (f.type.startswith('OID') or f.name.startswith('SH'))] #List polygon fields
polytemplate = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polygon,fieldnames+['SHAPE@'])][0] #Create a polygon template

#Insert pointcount-1 number of polygons
icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(polygon, fieldnames+['SHAPE@'])
for coord in coordinates[1:]: 
    icur.insertRow(polytemplate)
del(icur)

#Update their centroid coordinates to match the Points (I dont Think this is possible with the insertcursor, if im wrong please comment.
coords = iter(coordinates)
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(polygon,'SHAPE@XY') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            row[0] = next(coords)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: Hi Bera! This was exactly what I needed! thank you! I have a new question about the same situation. After replicating the polygons, how can I rotate them according to the direction of the points?

Comment: @AnaBeatrizFreitas Nice! Please accept my answer with the checkbox. That is a new question and a bit more complicated. Take a look at: [Rotating polygons by value from attribute table using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309624/rotating-polygons-by-value-from-attribute-table-using-arcpy). Spatial join the rotation attribute from the Points to the polygons.

Comment: I'm trying to use the script that you suggest n this post "Rotating polygons...", but there is an error that I can not understand.
_"Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"_

Comment: @AnaBeatrizFreitas I Think you should post a new question and include the code you have tried and the error message.