# Rotate feature around defined fixed point using ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, rotate

I have a polygon feature and want to rotate it around defined (fixed point). There is a Rotate tool in Editor toolbar but I can't define fixed rotation point. I am using ArcGIS 10.4 and want to know how to do that using this software.

Comment: You can modify the code in the answer to [Rotating polygons by value from attribute table using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309624/rotating-polygons-by-value-from-attribute-table-using-arcpy/309667#309667) and replace `row[0].centroid` with your rotation Point, for example `arcpy.Point(300000,6000000)`

Comment: @BERA I am not really familiar with ArcPy bu I could try. So the script is same as this from the answer. Could you write how to change row[0].centroid to my point. How that should look like if I have a lat/long of that point or if I have created point feature?